# Using a function to create a instance of a class.

Tags: python, function, class, object

To meet the specifications of a program I'm writing I need to be able to generate an instance of a class on the fly that can be referenced easily by other parts of the code.

I've looked around and can't find an answer to this, can I do this within python or not?

Thank you to all replies in advanced.

Comment: Yes, this can be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an Instance of a Class with a variable in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136760/creating-an-instance-of-a-class-with-a-variable-in-python)

Comment: uh `my_instance = MyClass()`?

Comment: This is very vague. What do you mean by "on the fly"? What do you mean by "referenced easily"?

Comment: I think you are asking for some type of dynamic instantiation.  Metaclasses may be an option.  Supply some code and someone will be able to directly assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

For example you could create an instance and `return` it from a function:

```
def some_function():
    some_instance = int('10')
    return some_instance

a = some_function()   # returns an instance and store it under the name "a"
print(a + 10)  # 20
```

You could also use `global` (I wouldn't recommend it though):

```
a = None

def some_other_function():
    # tell the function that you intend to alter the global variable "a",
    # not a local variable "a"
    global a   
    a = int('10')

some_other_function()  # changes the global variable "a"
print(a)   # 10
```